# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout' in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run following code which uses pythos 'subprocess' module.

```
subprocess.call(cli_args, stdout=client_log, stderr=client_log, timeout=10)
```

I am using timeout arguement, which is mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) to skip from this line if the subprocess stuck at the middle, by killing it.
But when I run this, I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 152, in <module>
    ret = runServiceTest(test_name, server_executable, server_extra_args, client_executable, client_extra_args, protocol, transport, 9090, 0, 0)
  File "test.py", line 102, in runServiceTest
    ret = subprocess.call(cli_args, stdout=client_log, stderr=client_log, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

What is the reason for this? How can I solve this? My complete code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/3dfe4f37c5db1400672f).

Comment: What's the actual python version you're using? From the footnotes of the timeout description "Changed in version 3.3: timeout was added."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by your `print` statements, you are using Python2.x, where `subprocess.call` does not have a `timeout` argument:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html