# python __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, subprocess

I have the following code with a timeout set to 60 sec

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ocamlopt', file], \
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, \
                     timeout=TIMEOUT_ECAML, \
                     )
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error message of

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

I have looked into [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264922/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-timeout-in-python-subprocess) with the same error, but the other user uses `subprocess.call()` while I am using `subprocess.Popen()` so I am confused why this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

`Popen` class does not have a `timeout` argument in its signature:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

You can pass the `timeout` argument when you actually communicate though:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: `subprocess.run()` introduced at Python 3.5 has the timeout argument and is now the preferred interface.

Answer (score 2):

Same reason. There is no timeout argument.

List of all valid arguments for a `Popen`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 1):

> the other user uses `subprocess.call()` while I am using `subprocess.Popen()` so I am confused why this is happening.

`call()` blocks until the command ends or the timeout happens. `Popen()` does NOT wait for the command to finish; it returns immediately and therefore it does not accept `timeout` parameter. You could pass `timeout` to `wait()` or `communicate()` methods which do wait until the process finishes or the timeout happens.